# Lightbox 2 responsiveness error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox2

I have created a gallery for my fictitious business on my own personal website, using the original Lightbox. The problem I am having is making the Lightbox images responsive.

Presently I have them at 4 across and I would like them to be 2 across for mobile. I have been looking for solutions to this for several hours and am unable to get an answer.

Here is the website:

[www.monikaandersondesign.com/gallery.html](http://www.monikaandersondesign.com/gallery.html)

When I make changes to my responsive.css file it takes no effect. Right now my styles for this images are as follows:

```
.thumbnails a {
   float: left;
   width: 25%;
   padding-right: 15px;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

When I open my responsive.css and add this code and modify it, it does not make the change, or it will change it to 2 across on the desktop and 4 across on the mobile version. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your website doesn't appear to be fictitious, as the link points to a real website...

Comment: I am creating this website for a class. I am using my personal doman  to upload the website.

Comment: It is a fictitious business

Comment: have you read your error on the console browser?